# Is there a way to make a server stablish connection between two clients without data passing on server?

Tags: c#, connection

thanks for any answer. 
What I want to do it's a server that will keep a list of clients connected and that are now expecting another client. I think many server for games work this way, they have clients that work as servers when they host, due to firewalls that block connections I don't understand how they make them hosts. How is this possible? What's the specific name of what I should search?

If you are willing to write any example code I got most of my experience in C#.
Thanks and sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, only computers that are not firewalled can be used as a public servers. Some routers with firewalls are adaptive - they allow application to unblock and forward specific port using UPNP technology.

There are also some tricky techniques for establising direct connection between two firewalled computers with the help of one public server, take a look at [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WCF, specifically using duplex TCP connections.

http://realfiction.net/go/113

You don't need to deal with firewall stuff in the clients (only server side) because TCP supports duplex connections at the transport level.